# WhatsApp Cloud API: How to check if a registered Phone Number is TEST NUMBER or PRODUCTION NUMBER?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, whatsapp-cloud-api

I have searched the Meta WhatsApp Graph API Doc + tested & used their Facebook Developer Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

But I am still not able to find the parameter to show the `TYPE` of the phone number:
[image]

I checked all the Phone Number params:
[image]

but there still no answer to my question, yet I still see others somehow able to check if a phone number is `test` or `production`

is anyone able to guide me on this? I am at a lost here

Comment: Can you share the API URL to retrieve phone numbers?

Comment: Hi, this is the one I am using: v16.0/{WhatsApp Business Account ID}?fields=subscribed_apps,phone_numbers{verified_name,code_verification_status,display_phone_number,quality_score,platform_type,throughput,status,name_status,certificate,account_mode,message_qrdls.limit(10){code,prefilled_message,deep_link_url,qr_image_url},is_preverified_number,messaging_limit_tier,new_name_status,search_visibility,is_pin_enabled}